# Changing icons with timeout in a loop

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I've got the following code which loops through each record in a table and sets the save icon to a checkmark.

After 2 seconds it should change back to the save icon. Except it doesn't.

I've used the exact same method for other buttons too and that works. So I'm suspecting it has something to do with the speed of which the loop goes through every record. Although setTimeout should be async...

Is there a better way of doing this? Each button should act individually. My last resort is writing a function that just changes all icons on the page and I'd rather not do that.

```
const iconToggle = () => {
    const isCheckIcon = btn.firstElementChild.classList.contains('fa-check');
    if (isCheckIcon) {
        btn.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-save fa-2x"></i>';
    } else {
        btn.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i>';
    }
}

for (row = 0; row < table.rows.length; row++) {
    currentRow = table.rows.item(row);

    ...

    returncode = save_row();

    btn = currentRow.getElementsByClassName('record-save')[0].firstElementChild;
    if (returncode == 0) {
        iconToggle();
        setTimeout(iconToggle, 2000);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
$('.table-save-all').on('click', 'i', function() {
    var table = document.getElementById('edit_history_table_body');

    const iconToggle = (abtn, state) => {
        if (state == "save") {
            abtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-save fa-2x"></i>';
        } else if (state == "check") {
            abtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i>';
        }
    }

    var currentRow, key, TotalNoBreakDec, OvertimeDec, TotalDec, StartDec, HourSchedule, returncode, btn;

    // loop through each row of the table.
    for (row = 0; row < table.rows.length; row++) {
        currentRow = table.rows.item(row);

        ...

        returncode = save_row();

        btn = currentRow.getElementsByClassName('record-save')[0].firstElementChild;
        if (returncode == 0) {
            iconToggle(btn, "check");
            setTimeout(() => { iconToggle(btn, "save") }, 2000);
        }
    }

    btn = document.getElementsByClassName('table-save-all')[0].firstElementChild;
    iconToggle(btn, "check");
    setTimeout(() => { iconToggle(btn, "save") }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: How is the ```icontoggle``` function getting ```btn``` variable? It doesn't look like you are passing btn to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the `btn` you want to change as parameter into the `iconToggle()` method. Currently, your loop goes throw all buttons and reassigns the -- seemingly global -- `btn` variable. So once the timeout for resetting the icon fires, `btn` is probably assigned to the very last of your button, and multiple calls of `iconToggle` in the timeout just toggle this button.

Furthermore I'd suggest, to pass a desired state into your `iconToggle` method, so that it will always be clear, what change is happening and an erroneous call of `iconToggle` won't update your interface in an unwanted way.

```
const iconToggle = (abtn, state) => {
    if (state == "save") {
        abtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-save fa-2x"></i>';
    } else if (state == "check") {
        abtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i>';
    }
}
```

```
for (row = 0; row < table.rows.length; row++) {
    currentRow = table.rows.item(row);

    ...

    returncode = save_row();

    const btn = currentRow.getElementsByClassName('record-save')[0].firstElementChild;
    if (returncode == 0) {
        iconToggle(btn, "save");
        setTimeout(() => {iconToggle(btn, "check")}, 2000);
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Regarding your comment and the updated code in your answer:

Compare your code to mine. You will see that I have

```
const btn = ...
```

inside the loop's body, whereas you only have

```
btn = ...
```

And therefore, this line of code

```
setTimeout(() => {iconToggle(btn, "check")}, 2000);
```

in your version, will have a reference to the `btn` variable which is declared somewhere outside of the loop's body (you don't show where). But as you are constantly updating this `btn` variable during iteration of the loop and also after the loop, `btn` finally is pointing to this element

```
 btn = document.getElementsByClassName('table-save-all')[0].firstElementChild;
```

and that's the element, all the `iconToggles` in the callbacks of the timeouts are applied to.

Declare the `btn` variable inside the loop's body -- or even better inside the body of the `if` -- and it will work.

```
if (returncode == 0) {
    const btn = currentRow.getElementsByClassName('record-save')[0].firstElementChild;
    iconToggle(btn, "save");
    setTimeout(() => {iconToggle(btn, "check")}, 2000);
}
```

All variables should be defined in the smallest scope possible, to prevent such errors.

Comment: I edited my original post with more info and the suggested changes. But the result is still the same as in my original question. The buttons on row level don't change back.

Comment: I see. As a 'recreative' JS user this was very helpful and I learned something :) I also noticed that using `var` still doesn't work but `const` does. Is this because var overwrites and const keeps everything that was declared on execution in memory?